# Regarding using mock stripe for e2e tests

Tags: java, spring, mocking, stripe-payments, e2e-testing

I came across stripe mock(https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock) recently, for local testing,

```
public PaymentMethod createPaymentMethod(Card card) {
      var paymentMethodParams =
          PaymentMethodCreateParams.builder()
              .setType(Type.CARD)
              .setCard(
                  CardDetails.builder()
                      .setNumber(card.getNumber())
                      .setExpMonth((long) card.getExpiryMonth())
                      .setExpYear((long) card.getExpiryYear())
                      .setCvc(card.getCvv())
                      .build())
              .build();
      var response = testMode? "Make API call to mock stripe with params" : PaymentMethod.create(paymentMethodParams);
      return response;
  }
```

Now I do not want to manually make http call to stripe mock server with http client and request body, Is there a way to change something in `RequestOptions` or use a different dependency to make the call?

Basically, I dont want to do, something like

```
String url = String.format("%s%s", Stripe.getApiBase(), String.format("/v1/payment_methods/%s", ApiResource.urlEncodeId(paymentMethod)));
```

just somehow override the stripe base API URL.

`Stripe.overrideApiBase();` is something useful, but its static to stripe java library, I want normal stripe calls to go through, when my e2e tests are running.

Comment: For E2E testing, instead of modifying the Stripe Client Binding library, you should really just use Stripe's Sandbox environment : AKA test mode in stripe's term. You can make test mode calls using stripe test keys like sk_test_xxxx and pk_test_xxx the same way as you would do it in product environment.

Answer (score 1):

[`Stripe.overrideApiBase()`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/Stripe.java#L43%27) is likely what you want; you'd just want to configure your app to only override it when running end to end tests.

Comment: yeah, that is the best solution I could find till now, wondering if there is some library for making stripe api calls other that `stripe-java`.

Comment: There might be, but it wouldn't be officially supported so it likely isn't worth the tradeoff for this specific use case.